# How to install the Mono package in a wineskin app?

Tags: windows, games, wine

I created a wineskin app for one of my windows games on steam (H1z1). I installed steam and downloaded the game on steam in the wineskin app but it crashes at launch in steam.

I created the wineskin using PortingKit, it offered at the beginning to install Mono but it also said I should skip it so I did.

Now that I'm troubleshooting i'd like to try with Mono in the wineskin, **how can I add it at this point please ?**

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, you can just delete the following file, and these dialogs will come up on the next run:

```
<YOUR_APP_NAME>.app/Contents/Resources/.update-timestamp
```

Of course, this dot file will be hidden by default and inside an application bundle, so it might be easiest to remove it by Terminal.

Otherwise, you could enable hidden files and right-click, browse contents to find it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried it but didn't find anything (using Terminal). It was for an Early Access game anyway.